# Does windows phone currently have APIs for proximity and light sensors?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sensors, proximity

Does windows phone currently have APIs for proximity and light sensors?

I want to access these two sensors, but can not find the API.

Is there some methods to use them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Sensor APIs available are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

If you really need it, then you should find it & vote for it here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform ; They are listening to the feedback, if the recent news stories of "native" code access coming soon are true.