# Detect Proximity Sensor Events in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, proximitysensor

I am new to Windows Phone Development so I would like to open a discussion on Proximity Sensor. I have searched a lot on Proximity Sensor detection event but couldn't find it. Is there any API or any event available for detect proximity sensor. If it's not possible then is there any other possible way for detecting proximity sensor in Windows Phone 7 & 8. Any kind of help would greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does windows phone currently have APIs for proximity and light sensors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380610/does-windows-phone-currently-have-apis-for-proximity-and-light-sensors)

Comment: Proximity like NFC/Bluetooth/Wi-fi stuff or something else? Like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

Comment: Not like that..I want Proximity sensor event of device. I don't want to communicate between two devices using proximity as u said above..