# Turn off screen during call Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

My question is similar to [Detect Proximity Sensor Events in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309399/detect-proximity-sensor-events-in-windows-phone-8) question.

I am developing a voip app in windows phone 8 which I want to turn off screen when user tries to hear through earpiece during call.

I checked in **Voip Chatterbox sample app** and it is working fine there, but I am unable to find the code section where they did it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by turn off screen? Do you want to disable user interactions?

Comment: I want to simulate the feature where there is a incoming call and user accept it and place the phone on earpiece and screen turns off(using proximity sensor). I implemented it using proximity sensor event changed in android.

Comment: First thing they have not used Proximity capability.How you checked that its screen off or just button disabling?

Comment: What did they actually used...that is what I want to know. I ran the sample code from this [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b) and simulated incoming call and touched phone to my ear and screen turns off. That is what i want to implement

Comment: Hello crack_head ,im trying to develop an voip app as well with pjsip library,and was stuck in how to run the sip library in background agent and recieve incoming call without using the push notification server.

and also,have you been able to make the call route to earpiece instead of speaker phone?

can you please explain how you are running the pjsua library in backend and how ur receiving the incoming call ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ID_CAP_SENSORS` Capability in `WMAppManifest.xml`.It should work as expected then.